# ReactJS: How to print jest test coverage results in file/log

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app

I'm using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) which uses Jest for testing. when running the command npm run test-coverage I obtain the results in the console, but I want to store them in a file/log. Is there a way to achieve this?

The command I use for test-coverage is `$ react-scripts test --env=jsdom --coverage`

Comment: Can't you just redirect the output? `react-scripts test --env=jsdom --coverage > test-report.txt`

Comment: That's what I'm doing, until I figure a cleaner solution